# Adding text to a product detail page according to the answer of a yes/no attribute

Tags: magento2.2, product-attribute

So I have items in my store that require more expensive shipping than others.

I want to be able to answer a yes/no question when I create a product and if it's yes I want the product page to have a message that says "**This product requires more expensive shipping**"

I'd also like the shipping price in the cart to be bigger.

But with the yes/no button there is now it only displays yes or no on the product page. Also every value I give to my new attributes goes into the "**More information**" tab on the product page. Where can I change this?